# using sql command add value returns syntax error

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

i have the following code but for unknown reason i get 'Incorrect syntax near ')'.'
the following code returns error. what is the reason for this error??

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO 
tempdb.dbo.##MyTable(Name) VALUES (@textValue))", conn);
int y = 11;
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@textValue", y);
```

Comment: The error message has a clue: `)`. With syntax errors involving parentheses, look at the code, and count opening `(` and closing `)` and make sure you have opened the same number you have closed. Also [please, please, please stop using `AddWithValue()`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see one `)` is unnecessary.

```
"INSERT INTO 
tempdb.dbo.##MyTable(Name) VALUES (@textValue)"
```

Comment: Why? There is one in the beginning and another  for text value so i would expect to have)) and the end

Comment: In your insert statment you have 2 `(` and 3 `)`, it won't work.